# Convert.ToBase64String(Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(mybytearray))) not outputting the same bytearray

Tags: vb.net, tobase64string

I have an login system in VB and it encodes the password:

```
'Hash password
'Create salt (randomness)
Dim salt(16) As Byte
Dim rng = New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
rng.GetBytes(salt)
For Each t In salt
    Debug.WriteLine(t.ToString())
Next
'Hash
Dim pbkdf2 = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(TxtPassword.Text, salt, 10000)
Dim hash As Byte() = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20)
'Combine salt and password
Dim hashBytes(36) As Byte
Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, 16)
Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, 16, 20)
'Convert to string
Dim savedPasswordHash As String = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes)
```

After that it saves it in my mysql database.

Then someone wants to login:

```
'Fetch the stored value
Dim savedPasswordHash As String = usersRows.GetString("password")
'Extract the bytes
Dim hashBytes() = Convert.FromBase64String(savedPasswordHash)
'Get the salt
Dim salt(16) As Byte
Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 16)
For Each t In salt
    Debug.WriteLine(t.ToString())
Next
For Each t In hashBytes
    Debug.WriteLine(t.ToString())
Next
Debug.WriteLine(savedPasswordHash)
'Compute the hash on the password the user entered
Dim pbkdf2 = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(TxtPassword.Text, salt, 10000)
Dim hash As Byte() = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20)
'Correct password variable
Dim passwordCorrect As Boolean = True
'Compare the results
Dim hashed(20) As Byte
Array.Copy(hashBytes, 16, hashed, 0, 20)
If Not hashed.Equals(hash) Then
    passwordCorrect = False
End If
Debug.WriteLine(passwordCorrect)
```

Every thing works fine, but the `Convert.FromBase64String(savedPasswordHash)` is not the same byte array as I originally put in but the `savedPasswordHash` is the same as my original string `Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes)`.

Comment: A quick glance at your code tells me you are going about this backwards. Hash the password that is inputted by the user. See if this matches the stored password. Don't try to unhash the stored password.

Comment: I already fixed it, but I never try to unhash a password

Comment: I saw this line `Dim hashBytes() = Convert.FromBase64String(savedPasswordHash)` and though you were attempting to unhash.